# $e^Ae^B$ when $A$ and $B$ anticommute

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, exponentiation

I know that if $A,B$ ($n\times n$ real matrices) commute, then $e^{A}e^B = e^{A+B}$.  Is there a similar identity when $A,B$ *anti*commute?

Comment: is e to A equal to {e^(a_i,j}?

Comment: @Alephnull No.  The matrix exponential is defined by a power series: $$e^A = I + A + \frac 1{2!} A^2 + \frac{1}{3!}A^3+\cdots$$

Comment: Have you tried induction on n?

Comment: @Alephnull You have to have a guess as to what form the identity should be to use induction.  Hyperplane's answer suggests that there is no reasonable form that I could have guessed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most general answer is given by the [Campbell–Baker–Hausdorff formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baker%E2%80%93Campbell%E2%80%93Hausdorff_formula):

$$ e^X e^Y = e^{X+Y + \frac{1}{2}[X,Y] + \cdots} $$

Which reduces to $e^X e^Y = e^{X+Y}$ if the commutator $[X,Y] = XY-YX$ is $0$, and to $e^X e^Y = e^{X+Y + \frac{1}{2}[X,Y] }$ if $[X,[X,Y]] = [Y,[Y,X]] = 0$.

However for anti-commutative matrices $XY = -YX$ you will find that in the series expansion infinitely many terms are non-zero, e.g. $[X,[X,\ldots [X,[X,Y]]]] = 2^k X^k Y$